# Pywinauto: 740, 'CreateProcess', 'The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto to open thinkorswim

code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").start("C:/Program Files/thinkorswim/thinkorswim.exe")
```

error:

```
  File "C:\Users\willi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1047, in start
    start_info)             # STARTUPINFO structure.

error: (740, 'CreateProcess', 'The requested operation requires elevation.')


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear. You have to run the script as Administrator. In some rare cases it could be additionally solved by changing to 32-bit version of Python or 64-bit version of the app. But running as Administrator is required anyway. Forcing elevation (restarting itself as admin) with disabled UAC (manually in OS settings) is another way, but it can be easily googled in ActiveState recipes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the elevation in windows by finding the IDE executable. In my case it was Pycharm. Right click and select 'Run as Administrator'.